# Branched coverings over orbifolds with reflector lines

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, fibre-bundles, orbifolds

It is well known that if $F\to B$ is a $n$-finite branched covering over an orbifold with cone-points then the orbifold Euler's characteristics are related via $\chi(F)=n(\chi(B)-\sum_i^r\frac{a_i-1}{a_i})$, where $r$ is the number of cones with stabilizer of orders $a_1,...,a_r$ respectively.

Now, I don't know if everyone would like to know what is the corresponding relation when $B$ has *reflector intervals* or *reflector circles*, as I'd rather... so  I dare to question:

Is there a generalization in this direction?

Comment: Rather than just accepting the "Well-known" identity, why not prove it.  Then you can ask, "what happens if I use the same technique in the other situation?" and you should have your answer. 

Comment: Could you explain why you find Greg Kuperberg's answer insufficiently detailed? Does the following observation help?  The identity really just says $\chi_o(F)=n\chi_o(B)$, where $\chi_o$ is orbifold Euler characteristic.  Now just count vertices, edges and faces, as in the 'usual' proof.

Comment: there, I found street babbling difficult to follow and retain

Comment: @janmarqz, I fear that something has been lost in translation.  Calling an honest attempt to answer your question 'street babbling' will not encourage anyone else to help you.

Comment: for "street babbling" I was referring to the style there on the Greg's link... but now i understand over this two word the meaning that your culture carries... excuse my clumsy english and for being to rude

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A detailed write up of what you are looking for is also available in Chapter 13 of [Thurston's notes](http://library.msri.org/nonmsri/gt3m/). Specifically, formula 13.3.4 on page 331, has the desired formula
$$\chi(O) = \chi(X_O) -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1} ^N (1-\frac{1}{n_i}) -\sum_{j=1}^M(1-\frac{1}{m_j}),$$ 
where $O$ is the orbifold, $X_O$ is it's underlying space, there are N points fixed locally by dihedral groups of orders $2n_1,...,2n_N$ and $M$ points fixed locally by rotations of orders $m_1,...,m_M$.

However, I believe the question addressed (at least in part) by Hurwitz in the proof of [Hurwitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_on_automorphisms), since the bound the order of an automorphism group H acting on surface of genus g is 168(g − 1) if H includes orientation reversing symmetries and 84(g-1) in the orientable case. The key observation is that the Gauss-Bonnet extends to orbifolds as well.

Computing the Euler characteristic for the quotient of $\mathbb{H}^2$ by the (full) [(2,3,7) triangle group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%282,3,7%29_triangle_group) is a good way to see this in action.

Comment: what about in the presence of reflector arcs and reflector circles? and say: $N=0$ and $M=0$

Comment: where reflector circle is taken à la Scott, in "Geometries of 3-manifolds"

Comment: @janmarqz It turns out those don't really contribute unless they are part of a corner point in the language of Thurston. For example, take an annulus $A = S^1\times[-1,1]$. The core of the annulus, $S^1 \times \{0\}$ is the fixed point set of a reflection. Call this quotient $Q$. Note, $\chi(Q)=0$. Also, $X_Q$ is an annulus and so $\chi(X_Q)=0$. Thus, the orbifold locus, a reflector circle, does not contribute to the euler characteristic directly (however it does affect the topology of $X_Q$, and so it implicitly affects $\chi(X_Q)$). There are perhaps other ways to make this observation.

Comment: For an annulus where only one of the two boundary circles is a reflector one is the same to $M\ddot{o}/\sim$. Here we have $M\ddot{o}/\sim$ where $(p,t)\sim(p,-t)$ for $0\le t\le 1$ over the Möbius strip $M\ddot{o}$... So, is the same fate?

Comment: @janmarqz I suppose I buried some point in the comment. It is a subtle, but reflector circles do not contribute to orbifold Euler characteristic. For the triangulation of an orbifold $Q$, any reflector circle would decompose into reflection arcs and vertices fixed by the dihedral group of order 2. For these vertices, $n_i =1$ and so looking at the formula in the answer above, these points contribute a $0$ to the sum. Thus, we can just ignore them. Again, I would recommend reading Thurston's notes, especially Chapter 13. It is rich with examples and many people have cut their teeth here.

Comment: ok thanks again @Neil, I'm going re-check

Comment: is your $Q=(S^1\times [-1,1])/\sim_{\rm ref}$ the möbius strip?.. is $\partial Q$ a circle right??

Comment: is it unique $Q$ among the orbifolds that contain a single reflector circle, but $\partial Q$ connected?

Answer (score 6):

[Yes](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/education/institute91/handouts/node35.html).